# gRPC channel reuse

Tags: python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

One of the company's developers was fired and I had to start making a demand that was about to be made by that developer... anyway

I'm not a python developer and I'm learning little by little as I work on this demand.
I have to expose via http and also via gRPC, some business rules that are written in Python....

This project will have to communicate with another service via gRPC and I don't know the correct way to handle connection reuse.
What I thought is, create a class that opens the connection with this other server, and start it in "__init__.py" of my service layer and use it, but, I don't know if this is the right way.

This project that I am implementing will receive a very large number of requests, mainly in the endpoint/rpc service, which will need to call this other grpc service from the other application, the reuse of the connection is something very important.

This connection with the other service would be used during the gRPC/http calls that this new service will receive

Answer (score 0):

A gRPC channel uses a single HTTP/2 connection and multiplexes concurrent calls within it by default out-of-the-box. It should be safe for your use case to just create a channel and share it across your gRPC-client/s. Check the [official docs on how a basic setup works](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/) on Python and give it a try.

To be sure that the default setup can handle your load, I would suggest to load-test your service under a feature flag before release. In most cases, it won't require any further tweaks.

Comment: Yeap, my problem is, where is the right local do create this channel to reuse ?
it is on "__init__.py" of my service folder ?

Comment: Where to do this depend on how you struct your app. If your init.py file is where you instantiate your "global state" then I would say: yes, create it there and reuse it everywhere else.